# One of my component in React is not loading while the rest of the components load fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I'm a beginner who's trying to make a simple website using React JS.
Here's my App.js file and the other component which is not rendering.
All the other components are rendering fine,Except for the one which I've provided code for(homePageProducts.js).

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import CarouselContainer from './Components/Carousel/CarouselContainer';
import homePageProducts from './Components/homePageProducts/homePageProducts';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Header></Header>
     
        <CarouselContainer></CarouselContainer>
    
        <homePageProducts></homePageProducts>
        
       <Footer></Footer>

  </div>
  );
 }

 export default App;
```

homePageProducts.js

```
import React from 'react';


function homePageProducts()
{

    return(
      
          <div>
           <p>Good morning</p>
          </div>
           
    );
}

export default homePageProducts;
```

PS I was just testing around with this component, Hence the simple code.
I've checked twice and I'm sure that I've imported homePageProducts.js correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

```
import HomePageProducts from './Components/homePageProducts/homePageProducts';
```

and render it
`<HomePageProducts/>`

Comment: Thank you Aravind. It worked.
Wasn't aware of the uppercase letter part.

Thank you

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. Remember to mark the question as answered!

Answer (score 0):

> make sure you have imported it correctly `import homePageProducts from './Components/homePageProducts/homePageProducts'`

Comment: I did import it correctly, No idea why its still not rendering the component.

Thanks for replying